# Deallocating LiveData when inactive

Tags: android, performance, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Some background info: I am developing an application that relies on Architecture Components to pass data between layers, and using the MVVM architecture.

My repositories have a number of functions that return LiveDatas and are observed by the ViewModel via Transformations, and then by the Views and their Lifecycles.

What I noticed is that when an Activity is stopped, the observer is removed, but the repository function that provided the original LiveData stays in memory. Furthermore, when a new request is made, a completely new object is created, so the memory keeps increasing.

The entire GitHub repo is at [this link](https://github.com/EmilioSchepis/QRSync), and specifically one of the functions is

```
override fun retrieveCode(id: String):
        LiveData<Either<QSError, QSCode>> {
    val codeReference = codesReference.document(id)
    val observable = MutableLiveData<Either<QSError, QSCode>>()

    codeReference.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        if (exception != null) {
            // An error occurred.
            val error = QSError.fromException(exception)
            observable.postValue(error.left())
        } else {
            // The detail must not be null, that would
            // mean that the code was not found.
            val detail = snapshot?.toObject(QSCode::class.java)
            if (snapshot == null || detail == null) {
                observable.postValue(QSError.DatabaseError.NotFound.left())
            } else {
                observable.postValue(detail.right())
            }
        }
    }
    return observable
}
```

I understand that the function creates a new MutableLiveData each time it is called, but I can't figure out how to make it return the same one, or at the very least clean up the old one first.

Here are a few screenshots of the Android Profiler showing the duplicated instances. [image: Screenshot of a duplicated instance][image: Screenshot 2 of a duplicated instance]

In this particular case, the `retrieveCode` is called twice. Not only the function generates two separate LiveDatas, it generates two for each call.

What am I missing? It might be a very trivial problem.

Thank you.

==========

EDIT: This is exactly how the [Guide to App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#fetching_data) does it.

Comment: Did you try making your observable class level in the VM

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a memory leak in the Activity observing the ViewModel which observed the repository.

The memory leak was caused by a bug in the dependency injection library.

More info here. https://github.com/emilioschepis/QRSync/issues/1